# JQuery selecting dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select a dynamic variable from a checkbox to disable or enable depending upon that state of the checkbox.
HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="only_once_1" id="only_once_1" class="onlyonce" >
<input type="text" id="temp_1" name="temp_1">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".onlyonce").change(function($){
   var parts = this.name.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/); 
   if(this.value == "on"){
      $("#"+"temp_"+parts[2]).disable()
   }else{
      $("#"+"temp_"+parts[2]).enable()
   }
});
```

The idea is that I may have many copies of these boxes that are added dynamically.  Any ideas how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: reduce the number of string concatenations `"#"+"temp_"+parts[2]` to `"#temp_"+parts[2]`

Comment: you could take that comment further and `['#temp_',parts[2]].join('')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 errors. Here is working code:

```
$(".onlyonce").change(function() {  // <-- error #1: remove $ parameter
    var parts = this.name.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
    if (this.checked) { // <-- error #2: use checked property
        $("#" + "temp_" + parts[2]).prop('disabled', true)  // <-- error #3: use prop method
    } else {
        $("#" + "temp_" + parts[2]).prop('disabled', false)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XR9me/

Main problem was here: `$(".onlyonce").change(function($) {`. By passing `$` as parameter to `change` method you overwrite reference to jQuery (inside a closure `$` became an event object).

Also you can write it a little cleaner:

```
$(".onlyonce").change(function() {
    var parts = this.name.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
    $("#temp_" + parts[2]).prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XR9me/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over your HTML structure, you can:

```
$('.onlyonce').change(function(){
    $(this).next('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/XR9me/2/

Comment: This is also a very good solution if I want ALL input of type text to be disabled.  I was looking in particular to select another element not necessarily a text.  Thanks though, this is a very elegant solution.

Comment: @Jon: it does not act on ALL inputs.  It acts on the next element following the checkbox, only if it is a text input.  If the element following is not, it doesn't do anything.  If the textbox comes after another element, you either went to use `siblings('input').eq(0)` or `.nextAll('input').eq(0)`.  Which will select multiple inputs regardless of type and the `eq(0)` gives you the first of that result set; otherwise you will need to use another selector  Additionally the `[type=text]`, as you may have figured out, is optional, which further filters the elements returned.